# Can a space be present when setting value of an attribute in a wsdl file?

Tags: wsdl

In a `wsdl` file : is it an error if a `space` is present when setting the value of an `attribute` ? For example :

```
<soap:address location="http://192.168.1.123/imfmobile/webservice/InterfaceTransfererClient.php"/>
```

Is it an error if I wrote :

```
<soap:address location = "http://192.168.1.123/imfmobile/webservice/InterfaceTransfererClient.php"/>
```

or

```
<soap:address location= "http://192.168.1.123/imfmobile/webservice/InterfaceTransfererClient.php"/>
```

or

```
<soap:address location ="http://192.168.1.123/imfmobile/webservice/InterfaceTransfererClient.php"/>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As WSDL and SOAP follow the XML specification, it does not matter if there is a space, tab or even a newline between the equal sign:
http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml11-20060816/#sec-white-space

However, it could be the XML parser is not 100% compliant to the XML specification.
I'd suggest not using spaces between the attribute name and its value.

Comment: Maybe a more readable format than the XML specification is the following document:
http://www.usingxml.com/Basics/XmlSpace